# How to encode a file in base 64 a certain number of times in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, encode

Lets say that I have a file named `input.txt` and I need to encode this specific file in base-64 a certain number of times (script asks the user how many times they want to encode the file ) and then save the result to an output file say `encoded_input.txt`. For example:

Lets say that the content of file `input.txt` is:

```
"Hello world_1 and Hello world_2"
```

And that the user of the script wants to encode the file `input.txt` 2 times.
So the script should generate a file named  `encoded_input.txt` which contains:

```
U0dWc2JHOGdkMjl5YkdSZk1TQmhibVFnU0dWc2JHOGdkMjl5YkdSZk1nPT0=
```

Hence encoding the contents of `input.txt` 2 times in base-64.

Any idea to how to approach it? I do not want to `import` any other module than `import base64`

Answer (score 0):

You could repeat the encoding function after loading up the file any amount of times you want using a for loop:

```py
import base64

times_to_encode = 2

with open('input.txt') as f:
    file_to_encode = f.read().encode('utf-8')

for _ in range(times_to_encode):
    file_to_encode = base64.b64encode(file_to_encode)

with open('encoded_input.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_to_encode.decode('utf-8'))
```

The `times_to_encode` variable sets how many times the string is encoded.